# How to write data to Firebase database?

Tags: c#, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

The following code will create entries "test1" and "test2" but "test3" prints to my Firebase database as an empty {} value.

```
DatabaseReference root = FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.RootReference;

root.Child("test1").Child("test2").SetValueAsync(JsonUtility.ToJson("test3"));
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the Unity documentation "JsonUtility.ToJson(object obj);" transforms the passed object to it's json representation.

You're passing a string as the object and JsonUtility cannot transform a single string to a valid JSON because there isn't any valid representation, so it saves a "{}" (a empty json).

Here's an example of a valid call:

```
public class Person {
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public int Age {get; set;}
    public Person(string name, int age) {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Age = age;
    }
}

DatabaseReference root = FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.RootReference;
var json = JsonUtility.ToJson(new Person("ltmenezes", 22));
root.Child("test1").Child("test2").SetValueAsync(json);
```

Comment: Here's the link to the documentation: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/JsonUtility.ToJson.html